# Android Studio: lots of errors when I run my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a noob with Android and Android Studio. The error messages make it pretty clear what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix them, or why they occurred in the first place, so any help greatly appreciated. I am on Ubuntu 14.04. The project is setup with android 4.4.2(api 19) as it's target sdk.

Most(if not all) of the errors are of the "Error retrieving parent for item" and "No resource found that matches the given name" variety.

It says at the end to:

```
* Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

But I'm not sure what exactly it is that I would be running with those options...

Below is the output from the Gradle console(with a lot cut out due to it being way too long):

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:27: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:35: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:39: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:39: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:241: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:245: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:174: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:176: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:177: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:175: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:172: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:212: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.yerman.sunshine.app -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:217: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:218: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:220: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:228: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:229: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:230: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:231: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:232: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:233: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:234: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:237: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:239: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:240: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:241: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:245: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:247: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:248: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:249: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:250: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:172: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:212: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.063 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Material TextAppearance classes are part of Android L. You need to target API level 21 for your build (and make sure those SDK's are installed.)

Comment: I basically uninstalled all the other sdk packages except android 5.0. This did the trick. Thanks. I didn't install L myself, so it seems strange to me that it was there.

Comment: The values-21 directory was probably created by Android Studio as part of a template. You don't necessarily need to uninstall all the other SDK packages, but just set your target build to Android L.

Comment: hey, my app stopped working again when i reinstalled api 19 and tried to target that again as I didn't want to be restricted to api 21. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706220/what-sdk-versions-do-i-need-installed

Comment: Looks like you got some feedback on the other thread. Targeting the newest version SDK isn't going to drop support for older versions, it's just going to take those newest build tools. If possible, you should always try targeting and compiling with the newest SDK level.