# What sdk versions do I need installed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**OS: Ubuntu 14.04 -- IDE: Android Studio**

I am having trouble getting my app to run. Currently android `4.4.2(api 19)` is my target sdk, and my minimum is `2.3.3(api 10)`. So my `build.gradle` looks like this(just the relevant bit):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yerman.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

However, my app won't run. When I press the run button, android studio doesn't freeze completely, but says I am getting 101 errors, and won't let me look at the Gradle console or event log. I believe from seeing errors earlier though that they are like those listed at the end of this post. I asked a question on here earlier, when I was having a similar problem, and by uninstalling all but the Android 5.0(API 21) I got my app working. But I don't want to be restricted to that api. That previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704813/android-studio-lots-of-errors-when-i-run-my-app). What sdk versions or other downloads from the sdk manager should I have installed to make this work? It occurred to me I might need all versions between my minimum and my target SDKs... is this the case?

Complete list of what I currently have installed:

**Tools:**

- Android SDK Tools           23.0.5
- Android SDK Platform-tools  21
- Android SDK Build-tools     21.1

**Android 5.0(API 21):**

- sdk platform
- Intel x86 Atom system image
- Google APIs
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom system image

**Android 4.4.2(API 19):**

- sdk platform
- intel x86 atom system image
- Google APIs (x86 system image)

**Extras:**

- Android support Repository 8
- Android support Library    21.0.1

**Errors from Gradle console(edited: full output was too long):**

```
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:27: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:35: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:39: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:39: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:241: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:245: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:174: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:176: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:177: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:175: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:172: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:212: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
/home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.yerman.sunshine.app -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v11/values.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v14/values.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:217: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:218: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:220: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:228: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:229: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:230: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:231: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:232: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:233: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:234: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:237: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:239: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:240: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:241: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:245: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:247: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:248: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:249: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:250: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:172: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:212: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    /home/yerman/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine2/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, i have this setup:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.serviceexamples"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

and that seems to be a winning combination :)

Comment: Have you set a minimum sdk version? Also, is your targeted sdk version the same as your compiled one?

Comment: Does this support all versions between 15 and 21 even if I only have for instance, 21 installed?

Comment: I was under the impression that Android 4.4.2(kitkat) API 19 was the most recent stable version, if that's the case, how can I target that instead? The settings you show me here are working, but I'm not sure why I can't use for instance, API 19 instead without errors

Comment: i think for compileSdkVersion 19, the matching or compatible buildToolsVersion is 20 or something like that. You have to match those two versions up to make gradle happy.